# Firestore security rule - how to secure subcollection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to ask what is the best way to secure Firestore subcollections.

Here is my problem: I have a user collection where there is a document named as the user id. I also have a collection inside that document with some information including the user id (again). Is there an easy way to give access to every document nested in subcollection of the the user document?

So far I wrote the following. I can access the first document (the one called i6mg... but not the second called DxDt...)

```
  match /users/{user} {
  allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
  allow write: if false;

    match /wordScores/{doc} {
    allow read : if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    allow write;
    }

    match /groupScores/{doc} {
    allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
    allow write;
    }

  }
```

Extra question: is there a way to secure all document without having the user id included in every document?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Thanks Doug for the suggestion. I have added the following code and probably got in some other problems...

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{uid}/{document=**} {
          allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid;
          allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid;
        }
  }
}
```

It looks like I am giving my users access to the subcollection but not to the main collection. The following code for example does not produce results and it catches an exception

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('userId', isEqualTo: userId).limit(1).getDocuments();
```

Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the UID of the user as the ID of their top-level document, **and** you want all of the documents in all of the subcollections to have the same access as that document, use a recursive wildcard:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

You have to be using security rules version 2 to get the recursive wildcard syntax.  Note that regular wildcards just becomes variables you can use directly in rules.  You don't have to reach into a document field as you are now.

Comment: Doug Stevenson, at first I forgot to add 'rules_version = '2'' but it worked anyway. How is it possible? If I add version 2, then it does not work. Here is the error in flutter when I try to get access to the users collection: PlatformException(Error 7, FIRFirestoreErrorDomain, Missing or insufficient permissions.)

Comment: It would work for subcollections, but not the main collection.

Comment: understood! so do you have any suggestion on how can I also add a rule to give read access to the main user collection? I would like each user to read their document (named as their uid) in the users collection as well as all the other document in any subcollection

Comment: What I'm showing should work for rules version 2.  Are you saying you can't use version 2?  You will have to be more specific about what exactly you are doing that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I have edited the post with more information. I am trying to use version 2 but still I do not seem to get access to the main collection (while it seems I have access to sub collections)

Comment: Your query is now invalid for the rules.  The rules I proposed only allow individual document get() where the UID matches.  There is no need to perform a query with a where clause when you already know the ID of the document.  If you do need to allow filter on the userID field, you will need to adjust the rules to look at the document field as well as the document ID.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also use this exact structure, except that my documents in the subcollection ( the root is user's uid) do not that a field userId). I applied this rule and it is secure. The problem is that I tried to hardcode a different user's uid and then that user could perform firestore operations. I think this is also a security issue because you can simply brute force the application and guess the uid and access another user's data. Or perhaps I am missing something, please explain then :)